# noWrap in Vue2Leaflet?

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

How can we stop infinite tile scroll with vue2leaflet?

I suspect it's something like

```
<l-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center" :noWrap="true" :bounds="maxBounds">
```

```
maxBounds: [[-90, -180],[90, 180]]
```

But this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

The [`noWrap`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#gridlayer-nowrap) option is supposed to be a Tile (Grid) Layer option, not a map option.